# Something is copied to my clipboard that I didn't save there?

Tags: copy-paste

I'm running Android version 10 on a Galaxy A51. I'm fairly sure that nobody had physical access to it because it was in my pocket.

The link itself is the phrase "look at this cutie" and a twitter link. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Every app can have read/write access to clipboard without user interaction. There's an AppOp permission named WRITE_CLIPBOARD which governs this access. There's also a timestamp associated with the permission. So you can check that using ADB to find out which apps accessed the clipboard in last few hours or a day. If not comfortable with CLI, you can find my app helpful: https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX. Search for `WRITE_CLIPBOARD&:TIME` in the app.